HP RP7 RETAIL SYSTEM MODEL 7800 Ubuntu Installation
Please can someone advise if Ubuntu22.04 can be installed on HP RP7 RETAIL SYSTEM MODEL 7800? also where I can download all the drivers for HP 7800 peripherals?

Does this answer your question? Will my device work with Ubuntu?

As bit older system, you may want a lightweight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors)  I use Kubuntu which is more a mid-weight flavor on both old & newer systems. Old system only had 1.5GB of RAM with with external SSD worked reasonably well.
